# How do I remove a button from being displayed on the canvas after a function is called in p5js?

Tags: javascript, function, button, p5.js

I'm a beginner in p5js and I'm trying to figure out how to remove the button I added to function setup from being displayed on the canvas when function drawInstructions is called, but I can't figure out how. It's supposed to be that when you click on the playButton, it takes you to function drawInstructions (where instructions will be displayed), but I can't figure out how to remove the playButton from being displayed on the canvas when function drawInstructions is called. It just stays on the canvas.

When I tried to put the remove syntax in function setup, the button disappears from the screen before it can even call on function drawInstructions. If I put it the remove syntax in function drawInstructions it says that playButton hasn't been defined.

```
function preload() {
 title = loadImage("title.png");
  optimaFont = loadFont("Optima-ExtraBlack.otf"); // downloaded font from online
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(512, 384);
  background(title);

  let red1 = color(237, 39, 36);
  var playButton = createButton("PLAY");
  playButton.mousePressed(drawInstructions);
  playButton.position(212, 299);
  playButton.style("font-family", "Optima bold");
  playButton.style("font-size", "30px");
  playButton.style("background-color", red1);
}

function drawInstructions() {
  background(0);
}
```

Comment: https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Element/remove

Comment: I tried to do that already but if I put it in function setup, it disappears from the screen before it can even call on function drawInstructions. If I put it in function drawInstructions it says that playButton hasn't been defined.

Comment: Declare the button outsite of the setup function.

Comment: Please use `const` or `let` in front of all your variable declarations to avoid polluting the window (p5 already does this enough as is...). Konrad is correct: any variables that you want to be visible from both `setup` and `draw` need to be declared in the enclosing, shared scope. But you will probably initialize the variables in `setup`. (Hint: put `let playButton;` outside of both funcs, and change `var playButton =` in your current code to `playButton =`.

Comment: I can't figure out how to input the remove syntax, I defined the playButton in the global scope but it's still not working.

Answer (score 1):

The confusion might stem from variable scope:

- if your code `var playButton` is declared and initialised with a value (`= createButton...)`) in `setup()`: this means you can only "see" the `playButton`  inside the `setup()` function, but not outside.
- You want to `remove()` (or `hide()`) the button at a later stage, in a different scope (e.g. from `drawInstructions()` function, when the button mouse pressed event handler was triggered)

You can declare `var playButton` outside `setup()`, thefore making it a global variable, visible from the any other function within your p5 sketch but don't initialise with a value. (`playButton` will be `undefined` until you assign a value at a later stage).

You can assign the value, in `setup()` where you can call `createButton()`

Finally, you can access `playButton` (since now it is a global variable) from `drawInstructions()` for so it can be removed).

Here's a tweaked version of your code to illustrate the above:

```js
var playButton;

function preload() {
  //title = loadImage("title.png");
  //optimaFont = loadFont("Optima-ExtraBlack.otf"); // downloaded font from online
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(512, 384);
  //background(title);

  let red1 = color(237, 39, 36);
  playButton = createButton("PLAY");
  playButton.mousePressed(drawInstructions);
  playButton.position(212, 299);
  playButton.style("font-family", "Optima bold");
  playButton.style("font-size", "30px");
  playButton.style("background-color", red1);
}

function drawInstructions() {
  background(0);
  playButton.remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.2/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Note that I've commented out the asset loading so it's easy to run the snippet.(You should see the button and a white background instead of your image, then the black background (and no button since it's removed)).

(Slightly off-topic, if you're familiar with using p5 libraries, you might find [p5.SceneManager](https://github.com/mveteanu/p5.SceneManager) useful)

Comment: Thank you! I initially tried to add the remove option in drawInstructions, but I think I formatted it wrong because I put playButton as a global variable and it still didn't work. This did though, thank you!

Comment: Interesting. It's worth paying attention to declaring variables: there's a chance you might experience [variable shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing). For example, if you had `var playButton` declared gobally, but in `setup()` you'd still initialise as `var playButton = createButton("PLAY");` instead of `playButton = createButton("PLAY");` this would result in a local variable with the same name (`playButton`) which will be initialised, but would "shadow" the global variable, leaving it `undefined`. I don't know is what happened to your code originally or not...